# recorrer body de correo vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Estoy intentando buscar una porcion de texto en el body del correo.
Por ejemplo ya leo el subject pero el body no se como extraer esa porcion que esra marca en rojo de la imagen Ref:00000
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es codigo que tengo

```
 Dim correo As Outlook.MailItem = Item
 SEPARO TODO EL SUBJECT Y BUSCO SIEMPRE LA PALABRA FOLIO Y UN NUMERO CONSECUTIVO
 Dim separados As Array = correo.Subject.Split(New Char() {" "c})

correo.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText
            body = correo.HTMLBody
```

Como puedo recorrer el body y sacar lo que busco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías obtener el [body](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.body) (que no tiene el ruido del HTML) y buscas con una expresión regular:

```
Dim clearBody as String = correo.body
Dim expr as String = REF:[0-9]*    
Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(body, expr)
Dim m As Match
For Each m In mc
    # hacer algo con el ref que obtuviste
Next m
```